# Error to precompile assets with rake 10.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

I was using rake 10.0.4 and I've upgraded to 10.1.0, but now when I deploy to my staging server it throws me:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `push' for LL("db"):Rake::Scope
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/seedbank/dsl.rb:11:in `override_task'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/tasks/seed.rake:42:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/tasks/seed.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/seedbank.rb:19:in `block in load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/seedbank.rb:19:in `each'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/seedbank.rb:19:in `load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/seedbank-0.1.3/lib/seedbank/railtie.rb:9:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `block in load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `block in load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:423:in `load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/alter/workspace/MyApp/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/alter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@3.2.13/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Rakefile doesn't have anything special:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

If I downgrade to 10.0.4 again, it works fine. Any clue?

Comment: no clue but it works downgrading to 10.0.4 too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known problem with the seedbank gem. The latest version of seedbank (0.2.1) still has the issue so the suggestion in the [seedback issues](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank/issues/27) is to use the version from github in  your Gemfile:

```
gem 'seedbank', github: 'james2m/seedbank'
```